# speed up views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, view

The following view contains 2000 rows(which isn't much) but it's taking around 4 seconds to fetch the value.

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `saving_account_ledger_view_new1` AS
SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN
            ((`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'DJV')
                OR (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'DCA')
                OR (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'DBK'))
        THEN
            'Deposit'
        ELSE (CASE
            WHEN
                ((`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'WJV')
                    OR (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'WCA')
                    OR (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'WBK'))
            THEN
                'Withdraw'
        END)
    END) AS `Particulars`,
    `mt`.`SBAc_No` AS `SBAc_No`,
    `mt`.`Tr_Date` AS `Tr_Date`,
    `mt`.`Tr_No` AS `Tr_No`,
    SUM((CASE
        WHEN (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'DCA') THEN `mt`.`Pri_Amt`
        WHEN (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'DJV') THEN `mt`.`Pri_Amt`
        WHEN (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'DBK') THEN `mt`.`Pri_Amt`
        ELSE 0
    END)) AS `Deposit`,
    SUM((CASE
        WHEN (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'WCA') THEN `mt`.`Pri_Amt`
        WHEN (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'WJV') THEN `mt`.`Pri_Amt`
        WHEN (`mt`.`Tr_Type` = 'WBK') THEN `mt`.`Pri_Amt`
        ELSE 0
    END)) AS `Withdraw`,
    (IFNULL((SELECT 
                    SUM((CASE
                            WHEN
                                ((`mt2`.`Tr_Type` = 'DJV')
                                    OR (`mt2`.`Tr_Type` = 'DCA')
                                    OR (`mt2`.`Tr_Type` = 'DBK'))
                            THEN
                                `mt2`.`Pri_Amt`
                            ELSE 0
                        END))
                FROM
                    `sb_loan_trans` `mt2`
                WHERE
                    ((`mt2`.`Tr_Date` <= `mt`.`Tr_Date`)
                        AND (`mt2`.`SBAc_No` = `mt`.`SBAc_No`)
                        AND (`mt2`.`Tr_No` < `mt`.`Tr_No`))),
            0) - IFNULL((SELECT 
                    SUM((CASE
                            WHEN
                                ((`mt2`.`Tr_Type` = 'WJV')
                                    OR (`mt2`.`Tr_Type` = 'WCA')
                                    OR (`mt2`.`Tr_Type` = 'WBK'))
                            THEN
                                `mt2`.`Pri_Amt`
                            ELSE 0
                        END))
                FROM
                    `sb_loan_trans` `mt2`
                WHERE
                    ((`mt2`.`Tr_Date` <= `mt`.`Tr_Date`)
                        AND (`mt2`.`SBAc_No` = `mt`.`SBAc_No`)
                        AND (`mt2`.`Tr_No` < `mt`.`Tr_No`))),
            0)) AS `Balance`
FROM
    `sb_loan_trans` `mt`
GROUP BY `mt`.`Tr_Date` , `mt`.`Tr_No` , `mt`.`SBAc_No` , `mt`.`Tr_Type`
```

The table structure is as follows:-

```
CREATE TABLE `sb_loan_trans` (
`Tr_No` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`SBAc_No` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`Tr_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
`Tr_Type` char(10) NOT NULL,
`Pri_Amt` double NOT NULL,
`Int_Amt` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Penal_Int_Amt` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FA_Pri` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`FA_Int` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Fa_Penal_Int` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Recept_No` varchar(10) DEFAULT '0',
`Disurb_Code` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`CREATEDID` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`CREATEDDATETIME` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`UPDATEDID` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`UPDATEDDATETIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Tr_No`),
KEY `IDX_SB_LN1` (`Tr_Date`,`Tr_No`,`SBAc_No`,`Tr_Type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Since, the above mentioned view is frequently used, the application's speed is drastically affected. Is there any way to speed up its performance?

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` for both the `SELECT` that uses the `VIEW`, and for the `SELECT` inside the view.

Comment: What is the value from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `saving_account_ledger_view_new1`;  _Probably_ that many rows are put into a tmp table with no indexes, then the `WHERE` clause is applied via a table scan.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM is available?

Answer (score 0):

> WHAT IS A MATERIALIZED VIEW? A Materialized View (MV) is the
>   pre-calculated (materialized) result of a query. Unlike a simple VIEW
>   the result of a Materialized View is stored somewhere, generally in a
>   table. Materialized Views are used when immediate response is needed
>   and the query where the Materialized View bases on would take to long
>   to produce a result. Materialized Views have to be refreshed once in a
>   while. It depends on the requirements how often a Materialized View is
>   refreshed and how actual its content is. Basically a Materialized View
>   can be refreshed immediately or deferred, it can be refreshed fully or
>   to a certain point in time. MySQL does not provide Materialized Views
>   by itself. But it is easy to build Materialized Views yourself.

See more here
http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Though that's what you would want to read

Comment: Nice Eric. Thanks for sharing. In financial applications i would say never. Data that can be stale, like tags and question counts by tag on stackoverflow, yes

Comment: Then again maybe you are on to a good idea, the rows are relatively few in the grand scheme of things. The MV is refreshed upon any new row inserts (note financials app do reversing entries not updates). So a lock tables call. Insert. Refresh mv. Unlock. Consumers of the quite frequent reads acquire locks as well. The question i have is are there legitimate reasons to return all rows for the front end or can it be optimized with a where clause

Comment: Almost always you should not "lock tables" when using InnoDB.